# Cocoa multidimensional NSArray

Tags: arrays, cocoa

I have this array:

```
{
campus = "test";
cidade = "rj";
informacoes =     {
    "cursos_graduacao" =         (
    );
    "cursos_posgraduacao" =         (
    );
    endereco = "Av. test, 000";
    id = 6;
    latitude = "-02.233225";
    longitude = "-09.969212";
    site = "http://www.teste.com";
    "total_alunos" = "";
    "total_docentes" = "";
    "total_funcionarios" = "";
};
}
```

this code is OK:

```
NSDictionary *infosUnidade = [self.arrInfos objectAtIndex:0];
nomeCidade.text = [infosUnidade valueForKey:@"cidade"];
nomeUnidade.text = [infosUnidade valueForKey:@"campus"];
```

but when I try get value from latitude/longitude/endereco/site... return null...why? These values are from array informacoes()

null for example:

```
NSString *site = [infosUnidade valueForKey:@"site"];
```

Comment: if it resolve your issue plz accept my annswer

Comment: This is not an array but a dictionary. Apart from that, how does this have anything to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code ,

```
NSDictionary *infosUnidade = [self.arrInfos objectAtIndex:0];
nomeCidade.text = [infosUnidade valueForKey:@"cidade"];
nomeUnidade.text = [infosUnidade valueForKey:@"campus"];

NSArray *arrforinfoside=[infosUnidade valueForKey:@"informacoes"];

NSString *strforendrose=[arrforinfoside valueForKey:@"endrose"];
NSString *strforlatitude=[arrforinfoside valueForKey:@"latitude"];
NSString *strforlongitude=[arrforinfoside valueForKey:@"longitude"];
```

This wil sort your problem.

Comment: Thank you i changed according to your condition.